# How can I use AFMotion::JSON object as a hash?

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

I have been using AFMotion with RubyMotion to parse JSON data from Spotify.  I am able to return the AFHTTPRequestOperation object (as well as a string), but I am unable to return this data as a hash.  Here is the code that I am using:

```
@arr =  AFMotion::JSON.get("https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=%20genre:%22southern%20hip%20hop%22&type=artist") do |result|

   p result.object

 end
```

How can I get this JSON parse to output a hash?  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your resulting hash is inside your block, that is, result.object is what you're looking for. You should handle it or pass to another function inside the block.